# Make index.html my landing page in asp.net mvc for christmas and new year

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to put a greeting as front page for some days on my site for Christmas and new year, but its still taking to my asp.net mvc home.

please how to do it, or I need to change my /home/index page for it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Open up the properties of the project, and click on the web tab. Select the Specific Page radio button. Simply type in the url you want to use!

Answer (score 0):

Change your landing page in your `global.asax` file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "YOUR ACTION" }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file "RouteConfig.cs" under the folder "App_Start". Then change your controller and action to Home and Index. The RouteConfig.cs file should look like this:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the existing index.cshtml or index.aspx to index1.cshtml/.aspx which is under views/home. then put your index.html and run the application